# How do you mass delete parenthesis and the text contained within?

Tags: notepad++

I recently wrote a book with a friend over the course of several weeks in Notepad++.

However, we have thousands of notes and the like contained within parenthesis. Is there any way to mass delete the parenthesis and the text contained within?

I could go through it by hand but that would take weeks so I'd like if there was a simple magical solution.

Comment: Are there any parentheticals you *do not* want to delete? There are options such as regular expression that could help you, but any parentheticals you want to keep would be removed as well. I might recommend a simple search for "(" so you can manually review them, but don't have to hunt.

Comment: No, each and every one of the parentheticals needs to get deleted, and I wasn't exaggerating when I stated thousands of notes. There are approximately 25000 different notes.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do a find replace using regex. 
`\([^)]*\)`

A good explanation of the regex can be found here https://regex101.com/r/eD3RPr/6

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work, it never found any matches to replace.

Comment: Try a search for `\([^)]*\)`

Comment: Wait, problem solved! Thanks! Now, Is there a way to delete dates and times in the same fashion?

Comment: Consider updating the answer with the solution that worked.

Comment: I used my own bit of gobble goop to fix it, but here you go: I used "\\([^)]*\\)" (Without quotes) in place of what RedEight gave me.